# Premature code execution with CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, javascript

I have an animation that is mostly working with jQuery and CoffeeScript.

I have come a problem though that I can't quite figure out.

```
class Cow
  move_head: (x, y)=>
    stander.animate({
left: 10,
  },{
    complete: @move_feet(x, y)
  });

  move_feet: (x, y)=>
    stander.animate({
left: 10,
  },{
    complete: @mover_in_test
  });
```

The problem is with `complete: @move_feet(x, y)`.  When there are no arguments, `complete: @move_feet` the code works fine and `@move_feet` is called when the `move_head` animation is completed.  However, with `complete: @move_feet(x, y)`, `@move_feet(x, y)` is called the moment `move_head(x, y)` is called.

I looked to what the CoffeeScript was compiling to, which is

in the `complete: @move_feet(x, y)` case to `complete: this.move_feet(x, y)` and 
in the `complete: @move_feet` case to `complete: this.move_feet`.

Thus, I think it is calling `complete: this.move_feet(x, y)` as soon as it parses the code.  However, how do I get it to delay this execution of the code until the proper time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make another anonymous function:

```
complete: => @move_feet(x, y)
```

Here are a couple of samples. First, something like your example:

```
class Sample
  constructor: (@x, @y) ->

  do_later: =>
    later = => @do_alert(@x, @y)
    setTimeout(later, 2000)

  do_alert: (a, b) =>
    alert([a, b])

a = new Sample(33, 44)
a.do_later()
```

You don't need classes for this, of course:

```
later = -> alert("hello")
setTimeout(later, 1000)
```

Note that if you want `this` to be preserved (e.g. inside a class), you need to use `=>`, otherwise `->` will be OK. Basically, here `later` is an anonymous function that **when** called will run it's body (`alert("hello")` in the above case). `setTimeout(later, 1000)` will effectively do `later()` in 1000ms.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `move_feet(x, y)`, yes, that is calling the function `move_feet` — just like in normal JavaScript. If you just write `move_feet`, that doesn't call it; it's just a reference to the function. What you want instead is this:

```
complete: => @move_feet(x, y)
```